# Understanding Vertical Movement Method in "Eloquent JavaScript"

Tags: javascript

Recently I have been studying JavaScript from [*Eloquent JavaScript*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/); currently I'm at chapter 15 called 'Project: A Platform Game'. I have been going through the code and caught everything but I got stuck with one method, when the author is solving movement along the vertical axis:

```
var gravity = 30;
var jumpSpeed = 17;

Player.prototype.moveY = function ( step, level, keys ) {
    this.speed.y += step * gravity;
    var motion = new Vector( 0, this.speed.y * step );
    var newPos = this.pos.plus( motion );
    var obstacle = level.obstacleAt( newPos, this.size );
    if ( obstacle ) {
        level.playerTouched( obstacle );
        if ( keys.up && this.speed.y > 0 )
            this.speed.y = -jumpSpeed;
        else
           this.speed.y = 0;
    } else {
        this.pos = newPos;
    }
};
```

I'm not sure how `gravity` and `this.speed.y` works in this context and I hope you could help me to understand it better.

My Question:

Particularly, on the fifth line `this.speed.y += step * gravity`, `speed.y` is not declared in the program anywhere before therefore I expect that program should give an error, is there anyone who could explain this to me if there's something else going on?

Plus I don't get how gravity is implemented here (why `step * gravity` for initial speed and then multiplying it by step again - step is the time during animation)?

I hope I explained myself properly and thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: *Does* it give an error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: It's just a method not called until the end of the chapter, but the whole code is not presented in one piece but no error is given when starting the game.
But when I try separately similar construction and call it then yes I do get an error if I don't declare this.speed.y first.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here because there's not enough code, but `this.speed` is probably a 2D `Vector`, which has `.x` and `.y` defined.

Comment: @VicoLemp -- Like you said, this code alone will produce an error - but because this is part of a bigger example, it's most likely implied that that `this.speed` is already declared.

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb, I'm really dumb! I focused too much on that gravity part that I forgot it, I'm sorry i took your time, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the rest of the code for that chapter, you'll notice that `this.speed` is initialized as:

```
this.speed = new Vector(0, 0);
```

And Vector is defined in the code as:

```
function Vector(x, y) {
  this.x = x; this.y = y;
}
```

Therefore, the first time you run `this.speed.y += step * gravity`, `this.speed.y` has already been initialized to 0.

(I found the full code at http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/chapter/15_game.js)

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb, I'm really dumb! I focused too much on that gravity part that I forgot it, I'm sorry i took your time, thank you.